# Linking library error c/missing dll/wrong version?

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml, glew

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 22 unresolved externals OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\Debug\OpenGL2.exe   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glewInit@0 referenced in function _main   OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewBindBuffer  OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewBufferData  OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewDeleteBuffers   OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewGenBuffers  OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewAttachShader    OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewCompileShader   OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewCreateProgram   OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewCreateShader    OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewDeleteProgram   OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewDeleteShader    OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewEnableVertexAttribArray OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewGetAttribLocation   OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewLinkProgram OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewShaderSource    OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewUseProgram  OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewVertexAttribPointer OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewBindFragDataLocation    OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewBindVertexArray OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewDeleteVertexArrays  OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____glewGenVertexArrays OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__glewExperimental  OpenGL2 C:\Users\Darek\source\repos\OpenGL2\OpenGL2\OpenGL2.obj 1
```

Like u see, I have probably problem with linking library. I was trying a lot of diffrent ways what can generate this error but I still can find out what it is.

I have project to do, from my school, with this libraries: ***GLEW, SFML.***

I use Visual Studio 2019. I think I linked properly libraries:

**Project -> Properties -> Configurations Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories**

```
$(SolutionDir)SFML-2.5.1\include
$(SolutionDir)glew-2.1.0\include
```

**Project -> Properties -> Configurations Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories**

```
$(SolutionDir)glew-2.1.0\lib\Release\Win32
$(SolutionDir)SFML-2.5.1\lib
```

**Project -> Properties -> Configurations Properties -> Linker -> Input-> Additional Dependencies**

```
sfml-graphics-d.lib
sfml-window-d.lib
sfml-audio-d.lib
sfml-network-d.lib
sfml-system-d.lib
opengl32.lib
```

I added dll files to debug and release directories: ***glew32.dll, sfml-system-d-2.dll, sfml-window-2-d.dll,sfml-system-d.dll, sfml-window-2.dll.***

I thought maybe I just put wrong version x86/x64 so I try download files again from this sites:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/2.1.0/glew-2.1.0-win32.zip/download

https://www.sfml-dev.org/files/SFML-2.5.1-windows-vc15-32-bit.zip

I just use only x86 version but still I dont have idea what can make this errors.

Can I somehow debug this, to find reson why it don't work? - Or I don't undertund the error by it self?

Comment: Seems you told VS where to find `glew32.dll` (Additional Library Directories) but forgot to tell VS to add this library (Additional Dependencies)

Comment: OMG You are totaly right. I spend few hours looking for solution.. and I didnt see this... I am unfamiliar with C/C++ compiler, linker and other. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

So because of my stupidness I just forgot add ***glew32.lib*** to:

**Project -> Properties -> Configurations Properties -> Linker -> Input-> Additional Dependencies.**